# React / Webpack component not showing, what's wrong

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

This is all new and no doubt I'm doing something stupid, but I have a component that I can't get to show up.

Here's my webpack.config.js

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');
var bootstratp = require('react-bootstrap');

module.exports = {
  devtool: 'eval',
  entry: [
    'webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:3000',
    'webpack/hot/only-dev-server',
    './src/index',
  ],
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    //path: 'build',
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    publicPath: '/static/'
  },
  resolve:{
    extensions:['','.js','.jsx']
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()
  ],
  module: {
    loaders: [{
      test: /\.js$/,
      loaders: ['react-hot', 'babel'],
      include: path.join(__dirname, 'src')
    }]
  }
};
```

Here's the index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Here's the App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {Button} from 'react-bootstrap';

import TestBox from './components/test';
var path = require('path');

export default class App extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>aaa</h1>
        <TestBox/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Finally here's the component that isn't showing up:

```
export default
TestBox = React.createClass({
  render:function(){
    return <div>ABCD</div>
  }
});
```

Comment: Does webpack run fine without any errors? Have you used the React dev tools to inspect the React app structure in the browser?

Comment: Does putting `export default TestBox = ..` on one line help?

Comment: what does your HTML page look like?  Does the `root` element exist?  Are script references to your bundles in there?  Are you taking any steps to ensure your `ReactDOM.render` call does not run before the `body` has finished loading?

Comment: Are you saying that aaa renders, but not ABCD?

Comment: side note, get react-developer tools, its a chrome extension that will be helpful. https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/09/02/new-react-developer-tools.html

Comment: It would be `export default React.createClass...`. No need for the intermittent variable, unless you want to organize it like in @Omarjmh's answer.

Comment: Andy's answer basically took care of it.  The problem was primarily in the component code itself, and once that was fixed up it was ok.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to put an equal sign in front of the export default:

try this, similar to how you have it in App.js:

```
let TestBox = React.createClass({
  render:function(){
    return <div> ABCD </div>
  }
});

export default TextBox
```

Comment: There appears to be something amiss either with the Test component itself or with the way I'm importing.  By commenting out the import at least I'm showing the <h1> element, but with it it in there, even "aaa" doesn't show up.